# Is there any way to create a face book album having description with php

Tags: facebook, image, facebook-graph-api, upload

Iam trying to upload images to an album . Is there any way to create a description for the album.

I am using the following code.

```
<?php
    require_once 'fbpic/library/facebook.php';

    $app_id = "xxxx";
    $app_secret = "xxxxx";
    $facebook = new Facebook(array(
     'appId' => $app_id,
     'secret' => $app_secret,
     'cookie' => true
    ));
    $fbcheck= $facebook->getUser();

    if(is_null($fbcheck) or !$fbcheck or $fbcheck==0)
    {
     header("Location:{$facebook->getLoginUrl(array('scope' => 'user_status,publish_stream,user_photos,photo_upload'))}");

    }



        $facebook->setFileUploadSupport("http://" . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']);
        // add a status message
        $photo = $facebook->api('/me/photos', 'POST', 
            array(
                'source' => '@' .realpath("ContactUs.jpg") ,
                'message' => 'It is a programming test'
            )
        );
```

?>

Comment: Yes, it is possible to do: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/#albums

Answer (score 2):

When you upload a photo to Facebook from an application and do not specify what album to place the photo in (`/me/photos`) , Facebook will create an automatic album for your application and all sequential uploads from your application will go to that automatically generated album.

If you want your application's album to have a description your application should create one manually and specify a description.  You can do this with the following code -

```
//Create an album
$album_details = array(
        'message'=> 'Album desc',
        'name'=> 'Album name'
);
$album_data = $facebook->api('/me/albums', 'POST', $album_details);
```

If the call is successful, the `$album_data` response will hold the newly created `album_id` that you can use when uploading the photos.   You simply upload them to that specific album id -

```
$facebook->api('/ALBUM_ID/','POST', array(
  'source' => '@' .realpath("ContactUs.jpg") ,
  'message' => 'It is a programming test'
  )
);
```

A good idea would be to store the relevant album_id along with your other user data in your database.  Remember to test the existence of that album every time you make an upload becuase the user could have deleted that album outside of your application.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable suggestion. Now it is working well. But I woould like to upload images to the album if it is already exist else would like to create the album. So how can I check if the album exists and how to get its id ?. Thanks in advance..

Comment: Like I said in the last paragraph, you should store the album ID for each user in your database.  If your user does not have an album_id in your database, then you know you'll need to create it.  If the user does have an album id you can test to see if it returns errors when you query `$facebook->api('/ALBUM_ID')`.

Comment: Is there any other way to get the details of a particular album by name  or to get all the album details ?

Comment: If you want to go by then name you'll have to request all of the users albums and manually find the correct id. (`/me/albums`)